# How to get Cucumber glue to bind with DataTables

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I'm adding Cucumber to an existing but relatively new Spring Boot app. The app has the following test runner:

```
package com.odinkirk.codecserver.integration;

// imports

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = { CodecServerApplication.class,
                            CucumberTestRunner.class },
                            webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports"},
                tags = "@integration",
                features = "src/test/resources/features",
                glue = {"com.odinkirk.codecserver.integration.glue"})
public class CucumberTestRunner {
}
```

Then, I have the steps laid out:

```
package com.odinkirk.codecserver.integration.glue;

//imports


public class MainStepsTest {

    private final String baseUrl = "http://localhost";
    private final String codecEndpoint = "/codec";
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    @LocalServerPort
    protected int port;
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MainStepsTest.class.getName());
    private List<String> originalMessages;
    private List<ResponseEntity<Message>> result;

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public MainStepsTest() {
        super();
    }


    @Given("the text message:")
    public void the_text_message(DataTable message) {
        log.warning("Running givenMessage");
        originalMessages = message.asList();

    }

    @When("the user encodes the message")
    public void whenEncode() {
        log.warning("Running whenEncode");
        encode(originalMessages);
    }

    @Then("the response is 200 OK")
    public void is200() {
        log.warning("Running is200");
        result.forEach(r -> assertEquals(200, r.getStatusCodeValue()));
    }

    @Then("the encoded message is:")
    public void encodedMessage(final List<String> encodedMessages) {
        // TODO: Update with live assertions
        assertEquals(encodedMessages.get(0), "foo");
        assertEquals(encodedMessages.get(1), "bar");
        assertEquals(encodedMessages.get(2), "foobar");
    }

    @DefaultParameterTransformer
    @DefaultDataTableEntryTransformer
    @DefaultDataTableCellTransformer
    public Object transformer(Object fromValue, Type toValueType) {
        return objectMapper.convertValue(fromValue, objectMapper.constructType(toValueType));
    }

    private String getCodecEndpoint() {
        return baseUrl + ":" + port + codecEndpoint;
    }

    private void encode(List<String> message) {
        clean();
        // stream the list of messages and run this expression on them. The ResponseEntity<Message> should be added to result.
        message.forEach(m -> {
            ResponseEntity<Message> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(getCodecEndpoint() + "/encode", m, Message.class);
            result.add(response);
        });
    }

    private void clean() {
        restTemplate.delete(getCodecEndpoint());
    }
}
```

Lastly, the feature file is in a directory called `features` in the test resources directory and looks like this:

```
Feature: basic functionality is in place
    Scenario: Encode text
        Given the text message:
            | message |
            | Hello World |
            | spam |
            | eggs |
        When the user encodes the message
        Then the response is 200 OK
        And the encoded message is:
            | message |
            | foo |
            | bar |
            | foobar |
```

Sorry for all the setup. All of this is to be able to ask the question: Why is it that when I try running the test in the IDE (Spring doesn't run from CLI for some reason; another weirdness), I get this error:

```
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:
@Given("the text message:")
public void the_text_message(io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable dataTable) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    // For automatic transformation, change DataTable to one of
    // E, List<E>, List<List<E>>, List<Map<K,V>>, Map<K,V> or
    // Map<K, List<V>>. E,K,V must be a String, Integer, Float,
    // Double, Byte, Short, Long, BigInteger or BigDecimal.
    //
    // For other transformations you can register a DataTableType.
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
```

I have a `@Given` set up the way the error specifies. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Just in case I've got a version weirdness (already tried downgrading Cucumber), here's the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.odinkirk</groupId>
    <artifactId>codec-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>codec-server</name>
    <description>Overbuilt Spring Boot app to practice and explore.</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <cucumber.version>6.0.0</cucumber.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.34</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I've tried using simply List for the `@Given` method parameter as the Cucumber documentation suggests that it should auto-convert. I get the same error. I've tried adding an automatic type converter. Still no effect. As mentioned above, I've downgraded Cucumber.

Comment: You have quite a few setup problemens in your code. For example you use `cucumber-junit` but you've excluded `junit-vintage`.  So that won't run.

Comment: When you say run from the IDE, which IDE do you use and which file do you run from (this matters).

Comment: Overall, you should make an MCVE and focus on the minimal to help you debug the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: My guess right now would be that you're using IDEA to run the feature file and IDEA guesses the wrong glue path for you. You can edit it in the run configuration menu. If this solved your problem, you can upvote https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243074/Do-not-suggest-glue-packages-for-Cucumber-v6.0.0 and maybe that will get fixed some day.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).